# Calculation in lotusscript

Tags: lotusscript

(I am not sure it is appropriate to ask my question here because maybe the solution is simple but I don't know how to solve it)

We have an lotusscript agent and I was assigned to improve that agent's function. But the problem is I only have a piece of code and the code is like this:

**(Code edited)**

```
Dim nYes As Integer 'new add 
Dim nNo As String 'new add
nYes = 0 'new add
nNo = 0 'new add
Set view = sdb.getview("ExportToExcel")
Call view.refresh   
For i = 9 To thisRow-1
    For j = 3 To thisCol-1 Step 2
        tmpstr = thisSheet.cells(6,j).value+"xxx"+thisSheet.cells(i,1).value
        Set thisDoc = view.getdocumentbykey(tmpstr)
        thisSheet.cells(i,j) = "No"
     '  nNo = nNo + 1 'commented this line
     '   thisSheet.Cells(i,j) = nNo 'commented this line
        If thisDoc Is Nothing Then
        Else
            If Format(thisDoc.ExpiryDate(0),"YYYYMM") >= thisStartDate And  Format(thisDoc.ExpiryDate(0),"YYYYMM") <= thisEndDate Then
            thisSheet.cells(i,j) = "Yes"
            nYes = nYes + 1 'new add
            'Suppose row30 and column30 to show the total of yes
            thisSheet.Cells(30,30) = nYes 'new edit in this line
            End If
       End If
    Next
Next 

' the result returns like this
'1
'3
'5
'7
'9
'...
```

I read the code, I think this code is about do some comparison (the for loop part), if value matches, show "Yes", otherwise show "No". And I have to calculate how many yes and how many no.

I assume the variable declaration and the setting is correct as this agent is already in use in the application and we have to do some enhancements in the agent. Therefore I may focus on the code that I have.

I am not very familiar with lotusscript, and I write the following code to try to find how many yes(s) and how many no(s) in the value.

Comment: What exactly is your question? This code runs through an excel- sheet (defined outside of the context of the code that you posted) and makes a lookup in the corresponding view to find a document with the key composed from two different cells in excel. If it finds it, it checks a date and writes "yes", if the date is between startdate end enddate... What does it mean, you have to "improve" this code?

Comment: You first write "Yes" in the cell and afterwards the number nYes to the same cell....  If you need the total than write the total at the end.. Perhaps you should change the nNo calculation as this will be always the total number of cells traveled....

Comment: @umeli, thank you for let me know the "Yes" and nYes are in the same cell. I don't notice that before your comment. Suppose the total will display in column 30  and row 30, so I change the nYes cell to this `thisSheet.Cells(30,30) = nYes`. and I remove the code `nNo = nNo + 1 
thisSheet.Cells(i,j) = nNo`. However the result is the same. Is anything I did wrong in the code?

Comment: I edited to the code in the question to keep the code looks clear.

Comment: To improve your code a bit, put the thisSheet.Cells(30,30) = nYes  after the last Next.... this only needs to be written once.. Then the nYes should contain the number of docs between start and enddate... maybe there is somthing with the  If Format(thisDoc.ExpiryDate(0),"YYYYMM") >= thisStartDate  line. What type is start/enddate ? String?

Comment: Yes, the startdate and end date are string type. Should I concern on that type?

Comment: You don't have to count nNo. You know the total: (thisRow-9) * round((thisCol-3)/2), and you know nYes...

Answer (score 0):

You just want to count the number of Yes and No results? Do this:

```
dim nYes as Integer
dim nNo as Integer
nYes = 0
nNo = 0
```

Then add `nYes = nYes + 1` and `nNo = nNo + 1` at the appropriate places.

When the loops are completed, the variables nYes and nNo will have your counts.

Of course, the next thing you're going to have to deal with is the question "Now that I've got the counts, what do I do with them?" I can't help you with that since you haven't given any indication of what the real requirement is here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your method, I revised the code and gave to my colleague to run the agent. (I don't have the full code of the agent, I only have part of the code to do the enhancement given by my colleague). My colleague said my code only display 1,3,5,9,... for the result. At that moment, I know I misunderstand your answer, so I edit the code in my question.Would you feel free to have a look and let me know the mistakes please? Thank you